# How can I use multiple C++ source code files in a project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

How can I incorporate multiple C++ source code files into one project?

I am trying to make a Mad Libs<sup>TM</sup> program.  I would like to split my code into mulitiple source files and only run one when I want to play that certain Mad Lib.

Comment: Are you familiar with the #include Directive?

Comment: @VanDarg: that's almost certainly NOT what he wants.

Comment: @CNoob9799: Are you referring to multiple projects?

Comment: no multiple source code files

Comment: @houbysoft--agreed! @CNoob, what exactly are you trying to do?  Can you describe your problem?  Are you trying to link files together in code or pull them into an IDE?

Comment: ok i will sorry for being vague

Comment: I am trying to make a mad libs file but i would i like to make my code into mulitiple source code files and run one only when i want to

Comment: @CNoob9799: You are using MS Visual C++? Just a Win32 app?

Comment: @CNoob9799 : One cannot "run" a source code file, it's merely text. Do you know about namespaces and classes and functions? _That's_ how modularization is done in C++.

Comment: @sarnold It's a common game where an incomplete sentence is given and you fill in the blanks with words that make the sentence funny. Like you though, I don't see how it could possibly be related to programming...

Comment: @CNoob9799, why don't you post your code?  Your question doesn't have nearly enough information in it for us to help you.  Code would assist us.

Comment: @Riddler: heh, that was my assumption, but I thought perhaps it was a typo for some kind of [_library_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) I'm not familiar with... It's pretty vague either way. :)

Comment: @CNoob9799: So do you have one giant .cpp file? MS Visual C++ would help you add different classes, splitting up header files (.h) and the source files (.cpp)

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest a complete redesign of your model.  Since you are new to programming, I'll try to keep it simple while still hitting on the important ideas you can lean from a project like this.

### Current model:

Each Mad Lib<sup>TM</sup> is a separate C++ file.  These files are linked together and one driver program decides which one to execute based on some user or random input.

**Problems:**

- Lots of code repetition.

  For example, each of the separate files will need to have code to handle user input, construction of the Mad Lib, and display of the Mad Lib.  This could be solved by abstracting your common code to another library and linking that in, but there is a better way.  Further, if you need to do something simple like fix a spelling error in your Mad Lib, you have to recompile your entire program!
- Lots of scattered dependencies.

  If you need to change the way you handle, say, user input then you have to alter *all* your Mad Lib programs.  If you need to add a new Mad Lib, you have to write a whole new program/function.  And, if someone else wanted to contribute a MadLib, they would have to specific guidelines to follow (unless you wrote them).
- Debugging is a nightmare.

  <strike>If</strike> When you need to debug, you'll have to sift though many many different source files for a problem.  This could potentially occur in *all* of your files too.

So, let's fix this model within the bounds of a small scale project.

### Suggested Revisions

There is a very simple solution that fixes all of the problems listed above:

- Abstract your Mad Lib data from the program logic.

  In this model, you have one driver program written in C++.  This MadLibs driver will load a MadLib from an outside source -- most likely a text file.  Now, all your program logic in one spot and is distinguished from the actual MadLib content.

This program can be implemented simply: just read the file word by word (or token by token, see `strtok`) writing the words to a completed output Mad Lib.  Every time a blank is encountered, prompt the user for a word adhering to the requested gramatical structure.

You'll need to specify a format for the blanks -- something like **#noun#** or **@verb** would work fine.

---

#### Including Multiple Files

Now, if you decide to put, for example, the logic of prompting the user into a separate C++ file, you can simply include it with the **preprocessor** directive:

```
#include "path/to/file.h"
```

If your files are in the same directory, your need only the file name.  If you do this, you may need to compile the actual *file.cpp* file into its object form first so the **linker** can find it.  You can do this with:

```
g++ -c file.cpp
```

Then, proceed to compile the rest of your application normally.

---

#### In Summary:

If you follow my suggestion, you will make great strides towards understanding modern programming approaches.  If you move onto a bigger project, you will find that *all* the data (even 'internal' strings) are pulled out into separate files and the program logic is separated from the content.  Further, common code is gathered together in either shared or application static libraries.  This opens the doors for:

- Easy localization.
- Trivial spelling or grammar correction or general altering of content.
- Much better scalability -- imagine a program with 100,000 Mad Lib files.
- Code re-usability.
- Happy programmers (=

Answer (score 2):

- Create the source files
- Write your code in the files
- Go to the file containing main
- Use the #include directive to add in the other source files
- The preprocessor will do the rest

I doubt if this completely answers your question but considering the low level of detail in your question there's not much else I can do.

Comment: Note that `#include` is only _sometimes_ appropriate.

Comment: @sarnold Just out of personal curiosity- when would #include *not* be appropriate?

Comment: It is better to divide the source code into .h header files and .cpp code files. The #include directive only need to add .h files. The compiler will link to .cpp files with the a file name.

Comment: @Riddler: Most projects only `#include` _header_ files and allow every file to be its own compilation unit. That way, you can compile each file individually -- drastically speeding up project rebuilds, since only changed files need to be rebuilt -- and making it easier to find bugs in files. An unmatched `{` at the end of the first included file would break your entire compile and you would have one hell of a hard time finding it.

Comment: Furthermore, as your project grows in scope, you may wish to have `static` storage for functions in one file that is not visible to other files, or you may eventually run out of memory to compile the entire program if the entire program must be compiled in one pass of the compiler.

Comment: @CNoob9799 If this "helps", why aren't you selecting it as best answer? Is there some additional info your looking for?